# Node.js : know what subnet(s) i'm on?

Tags: node.js

I already found ways to get the network addresses with Node.js (using `require('os').networkInterfaces()`).

But does somebody know how to find which subnet(s) (`/24, /16, /8` ...) I'm on?

The project involves scanning my own subnet using `evilscan`;-)

I'm using OS X

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to perform a CIDR calculation which can be done with modules such as [netmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/netmask).

```
var subnet = require('subnet').Netmask,
      ifaces = require('os').networkInterfaces();

ifaces.forEach(function(iface) {
  console.log(new netmask(iface.address+'/'+iface.netmask));
});
```

Or you can use [libnmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libnmap) and the `.discover()` method to detect and auto scan the devices on each interface(s) subnet.

```
var nmap = require('libnmap');

nmap.discover(function(err, report) {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);

  for (var item in report) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(report[item]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @moritz for the code editing, mobile isn't the best for it

Comment: Ah! That was the reason... Sorry, I should have guessed. Yeah it's weird on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can always execute ifconfig from your node script, then parse the output and extract the subnet parameter for the network interface you're interested in.